# how to pass id of a label to a function in c#.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have the following label.

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Modification" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#FF3300" Visible="False" Width="300px"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Message" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#FF3300" Visible="False" Width="300px"></asp:Label>
```

i want to pass id of the above label to the following method.

```
public bool date_Validation(DateTime t_Start_Date,DateTime t_End_Date,DateTime t_View_From)
{
    #region  date_Validation
    try
    {
        if (t_Start_Date.Date < DateTime.Today)
        {
            lbl_Modification.Visible = true;
            lbl_Modification.Text = "Date cannot be lesser than the Current Date";
            return false;
        }
        else if (t_End_Date.Date < t_Start_Date)
        {
            lbl_Modification.Visible = true;
            lbl_Modification.Text = "Invalid End Date";
            return false;
        }
        else if (t_View_From.Date < DateTime.Today || t_View_From.Date >= t_Start_Date.Date)
        {
            lbl_Modification.Visible = true;
            lbl_Modification.Text = "view Date cannot be greater  than the Start Date or lesser than Current date";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

How i can i do this.
Please someone help me to do this.

Comment: what do you mean? lbl_Modification.Id gives you that.

Comment: I have several labels.So instead of giving lbl_Modification i want to pass the id of the label.so i can use it any label.

Answer (score 3):

```
public bool date_Validation(DateTime t_Start_Date,DateTime t_End_Date,DateTime t_View_From, Label lblModification)
{
// Method Content
}
//Call this method with your label parameter
date_Validation(startdate,enddate,viewform,lbl_Modification)
//lbl_Modification -> its your label name
```

Answer (score 1):

Control's ID is a string, if you want to pass it as an extra parameter then change your method declaration to accept an additional param

```
public bool date_Validation(DateTime t_Start_Date,DateTime t_End_Date,DateTime t_View_From, string LabelID)
{
    #region  date_Validation
    try
    {
        if (t_Start_Date.Date < DateTime.Today)
        {
            //Find the control here 
            var label=This.FindControl(LabelID);
            lbl_Modification.Visible = true;
            lbl_Modification.Text = "Date cannot be lesser than the Current Date";
            return false;
        }
        else if (t_End_Date.Date < t_Start_Date)
        {
            lbl_Modification.Visible = true;
            lbl_Modification.Text = "Invalid End Date";
            return false;
        }
        else if (t_View_From.Date < DateTime.Today || t_View_From.Date >= t_Start_Date.Date)
        {
            lbl_Modification.Visible = true;
            lbl_Modification.Text = "view Date cannot be greater  than the Start Date or lesser than Current date";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

then your calling code would be something like

```
var isValid=date_Validation(startdate, enddate, "lbl_Modification");
```